# How to find more than one substring from a string in Python

Tags: python, biopython

For example if i have a string 'ATGAGGGATAGAGGGTTGGGAGAGATGGATAGGGGATAGATTG'
i have to get substring between ATG and TTG , as we can see there are two of these kinds in a string.

I am not able to figure out anyway to do it , plz help me thru it!

Comment: Is it possible for the `ATG...TTG` sequences to (fully or partially) overlap?

Comment: How about reverse search for 'TTG'?

Answer (score 8):

Using regular expression can easily get you there.

For example:

```
import re
a = 'ATGAGGGATAGAGGGTTGGGAGAGATGGATAGGGGATAGATTG'
print re.findall("ATG(.*?)TTG", a)
```

Output:

```
['AGGGATAGAGGG', 'GATAGGGGATAGA']
```

Comment: this seems not to find overlapping substrings. For more discussion see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390913/how-to-select-only-certain-substrings

Comment: What is the type of the Output we get here {list or strings or sequence)