# How to select only certain Substrings

Tags: python, biopython

from a string say dna = 'ATAGGGATAGGGAGAGAGCGATCGAGCTAG'
i got substring say dna.format = 'ATAGGGATAG','GGGAGAGAG'
i only want to print substring whose length is divisible by 3
how to do that?  im using modulo but its not working !

```
import re
if mydna = 'ATAGGGATAGGGAGAGAGCAGATCGAGCTAG'
print re.findall("ATA"(.*?)"AGA" , mydna)
if len(mydna)%3 == 0
   print mydna
```

corrected code

```
import re
mydna = 'ATAGGGATAGGGAGAGAGCAGATCGAGCTAG'
re.findall("ATA"(.*?)"AGA" , mydna.format)
if len(mydna.format)%3 == 0:
   print mydna.format
```

this still doesnt give me substring with length divisible by three . . any idea whats wrong ?

im expecting only substrings which has length divisible by three to be printed

Comment: The code in the question has at least three mistakes. I am guessing Line 2 is just an assignment and should be `mydna = 'ATAGGGATAGGGAGAGAGCAGATCGAGCTAG'`. Line 3 is not valid. Did you mean `print re.findall("ATA(.*?)AGA" , mydna)`? Line 4 should end with a colon (`:`).

Comment: Can you add example input and the corresponding expected output?

Comment: also I'm not sure if you want non-overlapping matches.

Comment: it can be overlapping but i want only those substrings whose length is divisible by 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the regular expression for that:

```
re.findall('ATA((...)*?)AGA', mydna)
```

the inner braces match 3 letters at once.

Comment: This is the right idea, but the inner group should be non-capturing, otherwise the result will be a list of tuples.

Comment: re.findall('ATA(?:...)*?AGA', mydna) is probably the most convenient version, but still only matches non-overlapping matches.

Answer (score 1):

For including overlap substrings, I have the following lengthy version. The idea is to find all starting and ending marks and calculate the distance between them.

```
mydna = 'ATAGGGATAGGGAGAGAGCAGATCGAGCTAG'
[mydna[start.start():end.start()+3] for start in re.finditer('(?=ATA)',mydna) for end in re.finditer('(?=AGA)',mydna) if end.start()>start.start() and (end.start()-start.start())%3 == 0]
['ATAGGGATAGGG', 'ATAGGG']
```

Show all substrings, including overlapping ones:

```
[mydna[start.start():end.start()+3] for start in re.finditer('(?=ATA)',mydna) for end in re.finditer('(?=AGA)',mydna) if end.start()>start.start()]
['ATAGGGATAGGG', 'ATAGGGATAGGGAG', 'ATAGGGATAGGGAGAGAGC', 'ATAGGG', 'ATAGGGAG', 'ATAGGGAGAGAGC']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using modulo is the correct procedure. If it's not working, you're doing it wrong. Please provide an example of your code in order to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

re.findAll() will return you an array of matching strings, You need to iterate on each of those and do a modulo on those strings to achieve what you want.